# Disabling Textboxes If user enters incorrect password 3 times

Tags: android

Im trying to create a login authentication and when the user enters incorrect password for 3 times.
The texboxes of username and password will be disabled and I'm comparing the user input to my stored username and password in my SQL database to validate the username and password of the user, How can i do this?

Comment: first question: when will it be enabled again? you can simply disable/enable an EditText via setEnabled(boolean value);

Comment: @JosephusVillarey it wont be enabled again after the user has successfully logged in, just want to disabled the textboxes after the user enters the incorrect password or username for 3 times.

Comment: but how can the user be able to login successfully when the textboxes are disabled? are we on the same boat?

Comment: now i think i see your point. check out my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use a variable that keeps count of attempts. then, when incorrectGuesses equals 3:

```
editText.setFocusable(false)
```

or

```
editText.setEditable(false) // Note that this is deprecated but replacement (inputType) has bug
```

Answer (score 0):

To set a EditText read only : 
Store a reference to your text box (EditText) from your create method and call .setEditable(false) to deactivate them when needed. Maybe you will also call a setText("") on it for clearing the value entered by the user.

Answer (score 0):

There is a relavent issue raised with Google affecting older versions of Android and some random newer devices.

an effecient, reusable, working fix is as follows (assuming this is inside an `Activity`):

```
private Static OnClickListener listener;

@Override
public void onCreate(...){
    ...
    listener = new OnClickListener(){ ... };
}


public void disableEditText(EditText t){
    t.setOnClickListener(null); 
} 

public void enableEditText(EditText t){
    t.setOnClickListener(listener);
}
```

issue report for setenabled(false) not working:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2771

Answer (score 0):

You should store the number of attempts on [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). Once this value reaches 3, just do

```
editText.setEnabled(false);
```

You should also check the value of this number in your onCreate or onResume, just so when the user kills the app and restarts it, the EditText will still be disabled.

On another note, you may want to look forward on whether it's a better idea to just disable the OK/Login button (I assume you have that one too) instead of the EditText.